# OrientDB java api SQL command CREATE EDGE

Tags: eclipse, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I have some trouble with orientDB(2.1.15) using the Java API.
I have added the following jar's to my project library:

```
blueprints-core-2.6.0.jar
concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.1.jar
jna-4.0.0.jar
na-platform-4.0.0.jar
orientdb-client-2.1.15.jar
orientdb-core-2.1.15.jar
orientdb-enterprise-2.1.15.jar
orientdb-graphdb-2.1.15.jar
pipes-2.6.0.jar
```

I want to execute the following command:

```
CREATE EDGE MetaInf2kmer FROM (select from MetaInfNode where accNo ='X17276.1') TO (select from GenomeGraphNode where seq=141) SET taxid=9646
```

via:

```
db.command(new OCommandSQL("CREATE EDGE MetaInf2kmer FROM (select from MetaInfNode where accNo ='X17276.1') TO (select from GenomeGraphNode where seq=141) SET taxid=9646")).execute();
```

I am using Eclipse Mars and exportet my project as runable jar.
I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.CREATE EDGE MetaInf2kmer FROM (select from MetaInfNode where accNo ='X17276.1') TO (select from GenomeGraphNode where seq=141) SET taxid=9646
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:72)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:42)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1400)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:67)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphCommand.execute(OrientGraphCommand.java:49)
    at odbMetaInforamtion.OdbAcc2tax.addTaxInfToMetaNode(OdbAcc2tax.java:112)
    at odbMetaInforamtion.OdbAcc2tax.<init>(OdbAcc2tax.java:40)
    at odbGraph.Testmain.main(Testmain.java:35)
```

I have already searched the internet, but i just found one maven solution.
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5105
Do you have any Ideas for eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
orientdb-server-2.1.15.jar
```

to your classpath

Comment: btw, you should update to latest 2.1.19, there are a lot of hotfixes

Comment: I have added the jar, but still the same exception

Comment: Probably this will help http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Tutorial-Installation.html (see the bottom of the page - Building a single executable jar with OrientDB)